# Difficulty computing a 2 dimensional density of the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$ at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I am trying to verify that the density of the cone in three space has 2 density $\sqrt{2}$ at the origin.

The m-density for a set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, with $1 \leq m\leq n$ is defined 
$$
\Theta^m(A,a)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\mathscr{H}^m(A\cap B^n(a,r))}
{\alpha_mr^m}
$$
for $\alpha_m$ the m volume of the unit ball.

So for the cone, we have
$$
\Theta^2(C,0)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\mathscr{H}^2(C\cap B^3(0,r))}
{\alpha_2r^2}=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{\mathscr{H}^2(C\cap B^3(0,r))}
{\pi r^2}
$$
I am unsure how to evaluate the numerator, it is given by 
$$
\mathscr{H}^2(C\cap B^3(0,r))=\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0}\inf_{C\cap B^3(0,r)\subseteq S_j,
  diam(S_j)\leq \delta}
  \pi \sum (\frac{\text{diam}(S_j)}{2})^2
$$
Where the infimum is taken over all possible coverings with each $S_j$ of diameter smaller than $\delta$.

It would seem that the diameter of any cover could get arbitrarily small, since the cone collapses to a point at the origin and therefore the intersection with the unit ball of radius $r$ again ought to be just a point. Is this intuition wrong? How do I compute the measure?

edit: I picked this point since it seemed to be easier, please correct me if I am wrong. I would also be happy for guidance in showing that the density everywhere else on the cone is 1.

Comment: pretty sure you just want the surface area of that cone out to $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1,$ which is a calculus exercise.  I think that calculation is going to give $\pi \sqrt 2.$ Note that it does scale as $\rho^2$ where $\rho$ is radius in traditional spherical coordinates. There ought to be a place in the book where they say Oh, by the way, for a cone you just...  So, how do you get the surface area when taking the segment $x=y$ for $x$ between $-1/\sqrt 2$ and $1/\sqrt 2$ and rotate it around the $x$ axis?

Comment: For points on the cone other than the origin, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516809/2-dimensional-density-of-a-cone-by-morgans-geom-measure-theory

Comment: @WillJagy hm I guess I don't follow why this should reduce to that calculus exercise. It seems that the intersection we want to find the surface area of should in the limit just be a point? P.S is it possible I am trying to do this example too early? I have not yet learned about lipschitz functions in the context of geometric measures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use area or co-area formulas.

In practice one knows that the $H^2$ Hausdorff measure coincides with the usual area for sufficiently regular sets.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula